# Best way to share authentication data between a node app and a rails one on same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, devise, express

I want to to decouple some parts in my rather large app and delegate them to an external node app, mainly for uploads but authentication remains a problem.

On the Rails side I'm using Devise, clients and forms will point to this new subdomain where the node app resides.

The node app is using express and I can connect to the shared database through the mysql module.

The idea is to use heroku for the main app, and delegate uploads to a node app running on a EC2 instance. In order to access the app I want to pass authentication informations, given that this endpoint will used by both API clients and web forms.

Devise has support for authentication tokens passed via URL, but I'm wondering what are your solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your subdomains are just 1-dot apart like www.myapp.example and uploads.myapp.example, you can share both the session cookie and the session info in the DB.  I would just code the node app to validate the session cookie on every request the same way devise does and you're done.  Is the upload subdomain user facing, as in does it render HTML to the browser or have to display a login form?  If so, than the shared session table in the DB is probably not the best idea, but if the node.js is just for uploads and can redirect to www.myapp.example when the session is not valid, all should be well.  Just make sure you set the domain field of the cookie to `.myapp.example`.